# In vue3+typescript devtools property does not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-devtools

In Vue3+typescript,
Property "devtools" does not existed on type "AppConfig"

[image: Type of AppConfig]

But, [APIDoc](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#devtools) was guide to this.

```
app.config.devtools = true;
```

What should I do? T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue already Handled...

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/1244